# Ansible: Build reverse dictionary with duplicate values in the original dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible

I have a `Ansible` dictionary fact `vm_templates` looking like this:

```
 {
        "HostedEngine": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", 
        "cpu-node0": "2d826ed8-1dbe-4b10-93a1-5ac9734462cb", 
        "cpu-node1": "2d826ed8-1dbe-4b10-93a1-5ac9734462cb", 
        "cpu-node2": "2d826ed8-1dbe-4b10-93a1-5ac9734462cb", 
        "cpu-node3": "2d826ed8-1dbe-4b10-93a1-5ac9734462cb", 
        "fp_gpu-node0": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "fp_gpu-node1": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "fp_gpu-node10": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "fp_gpu-node11": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "fp_gpu-node2": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "fp_gpu-node3": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "fp_gpu-node4": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "fp_gpu-node5": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "fp_gpu-node6": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "fp_gpu-node7": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "fp_gpu-node8": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "fp_gpu-node9": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "hp_gpu-node0": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "hp_gpu-node1": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "hp_gpu-node2": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "hp_gpu-node3": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "hp_gpu-node4": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "hp_gpu-node5": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "hp_gpu-node6": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "hp_gpu-node7": "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613", 
        "infra-vm": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    }
```

I would like to build a flipping dictionary from the above one, taking into account keys with duplicate values.
So I would like to associate each value from the first dictionary with its keys in a list, and keys having duplicate values in the old dictionary will be in the same list value.

Here is the result I'm trying to get, using `ansible` :

```
 {
        "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000": ["HostedEngine", "infra-vm"], 
        "2d826ed8-1dbe-4b10-93a1-5ac9734462cb": ["cpu-node0", "cpu-node1", "cpu-node2", "cpu-node3"], 
       "a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613": ["fp_gpu-node0", "fp_gpu-node1", "fp_gpu-node10", "fp_gpu-node11", "fp_gpu-node2", "fp_gpu-node3", "fp_gpu-node4", "fp_gpu-node5", "fp_gpu-node6", "fp_gpu-node7", "fp_gpu-node8", "fp_gpu-node9", "hp_gpu-node0", "hp_gpu-node1", "hp_gpu-node2", "hp_gpu-node3", "hp_gpu-node4", "hp_gpu-node5", "hp_gpu-node6", "hp_gpu-node7"]
 }
```

In python I would have written something like :

```
reverse_templates = {} 


for key, value in vm_template.items(): 
    if value not in reverse_templates: 
        reverse_templates[value] = [key] 
    else: 
        reverse_templates[value].append(key)
```

Here is what I tried in `ansible`, which doesn't work :

```
- name: "Associate each template with related VMs list"
  set_fact:
    reverse_templates: "{{reverse_templates|default({})|combine({item.value:{% if item.value not in reverse_teplates %}value[item.key]{% else %}reverse_templates[item.value] + [item.key]{% endif %}})}}"
  loop: "{{lookup('dict', vm_templates)}}"
```

Here is the error :

> TASK [Associate each template with related VMs list] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected '%'. String:
> {{reverse_templates|default({})|combine({item.value:{% if item.value
> not in reverse_teplates %}value[item.key]{% else
> %}reverse_templates[item.value] + [item.key]{% endif %}})}}"}

Any good approach to get there using `Ansible`?

Comment: You may just want to make a custom filter plugin, so you can write it in Python.

Answer (score 2):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        reverse_templates: "{{ reverse_templates|default([]) +
                               [{item: vm_templates|
                                       dict2items|
                                       selectattr('value', 'eq', item)|
                                       map(attribute='key')|
                                       list}] }}"
      loop: "{{ vm_templates.values()|unique|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: reverse_templates
```

give

```yaml
  reverse_templates:
  - a08901c0-50a5-4e2f-b6d7-b11b69a32613:
    - fp_gpu-node0
    - fp_gpu-node1
    - fp_gpu-node10
    - fp_gpu-node11
    - fp_gpu-node2
    - fp_gpu-node3
    - fp_gpu-node4
    - fp_gpu-node5
    - fp_gpu-node6
    - fp_gpu-node7
    - fp_gpu-node8
    - fp_gpu-node9
    - hp_gpu-node0
    - hp_gpu-node1
    - hp_gpu-node2
    - hp_gpu-node3
    - hp_gpu-node4
    - hp_gpu-node5
    - hp_gpu-node6
    - hp_gpu-node7
  - 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:
    - HostedEngine
    - infra-vm
  - 2d826ed8-1dbe-4b10-93a1-5ac9734462cb:
    - cpu-node0
    - cpu-node1
    - cpu-node2
    - cpu-node3
```

The Ansible code is similar to Python

```py
for key in set(vm_templates.values()):
    reverse_templates[key] = [k for k,v in vm_templates.items() if v == key]
print(reverse_templates)
```

---

[**json_query**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter)

The task below produces the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        reverse_templates: "{{ reverse_templates|default([]) +
                               [{item: vm_templates|
                                       dict2items|
                                       json_query(query)}] }}"
      loop: "{{ vm_templates.values()|unique|list }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?value == '{{ item }}'].key"
```

Comment: Thx @Vladimir.
Running the code exactly as above says there is no test named  `'eq'`, removing quotes from `eq`  give the below error : 
`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({u'reverse_templates': u\"{{ reverse_templates|default([]) + [{item: vm_templates| dict2items| selectattr('value', eq, item)| map(attribute='key')| list}] }}\"}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: key must be a string\n\n....`
Please did you test and does it work fine on your side ?

Comment: Yes. It's working with `Ansible 2.9.6` and `python3-jinja2 2.10.1-2`. See [eq](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#eq). Try "==" it's an equivalent.

Comment: I wonder why did you post **irrelevant syntax error** instead of **relevant** missing 'eq'? Make sure you understand [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before commenting. Especially the part about the verification in this case.

Comment: Sorry you're right, here is the error, which is the same either with `eq`, `==` or `equalto` : 
`An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TemplateRuntimeError: no test named '=='
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}.`

This does not seem like an Ansible issue but rather an issue with your environment, cause the box I'm working on has an older `jinja2`  version, and that's the same version of `jinja2`  `ansible` is using.

Comment: I wrote a little playbook to show the `jinja2` version used by ansible, which output this :
`TASK [jin_ver] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "msg": "2.7.2"}`

`[root@lisa tmp]# rpm -q python-jinja2
python-jinja2-2.7.2-4.el7.noarch
[root@lisa tmp]#` 

I don't know if there is an equivalent retro-compatible to achieve what we are trying to do.

Comment: `[root@lisa tmp]# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
[root@lisa tmp]#`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219517/discussion-between-nixmind-and-vladimir-botka).